# No Subversion Plugin Available for netbeans

Tags: windows, svn, plugins, netbeans

I think there are missing repositories for netbeans plugins in my installation.

I can't find subversion in my '**available plugins**' tab.

Here are my repositories:

- http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/final/thirdparty/catalog.xml.gz
- http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/final/stable/catalog.xml.gz
- http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/final/beta/catalog.xml.gz
- http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/6.9/catalog.xml.gz

Is there anyone knows how to add the subversion plugin? FYI, I'm on windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Guided tour of Subversion](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html) within NetBeans; the tour walks you through the details in getting it set up within the IDE.

Comment: I already read that through. If you read it, you'll see that there is note: "Note for Windows users: You can install a bundled Subversion client as a NetBeans IDE plugin. Go to Tools > Plugins, open the Available Plugins tab, and install the Bundled Subversion Client for Windows." I can't find this plugin.

Comment: @silent What NetBeans version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.9.1

Comment: @silent ...and if you go to _Team_ -> _Subversion_ nothing exists?